# How to bind a NSString into a sqlite sql statement

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, nsstring

Hi all
I am using the sqlite3 database in my iphone application but seems like I have a problem when I try to update a object in the table. Can anyone shortly explain how NSStrings can be added as placeholder? (Yes I know an ID should not be a NSString :))

This code snipplet updates the table:

```
NSString *affectedFactId = [fact factId];
char const *sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE facts SET isFavorite = 'yes' WHERE id=1");
```

This code snipplet fails:

```
NSString *affectedFactId = [fact factId];
char const *sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE facts SET isFavorite = 'yes' WHERE id='%@'", affectedFactId);
```

Thanks for explaining,
Cheers,
Doonot

Comment: 1. The id column of your facts table is an int. Provide an int in the sql statement.
2. Check out the documentation for NSString's intValue method.

Comment: Dammit, I just tried and you are right. Thanks man. Funny, the answer is basically in my question!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set id to be an int not a string as you do. The intValue of NSString class will do that for you.

Comment: Thanks to falconcreek, I changed it to this and it works now:

    NSInteger *affectedFactId = [[fact factId] intValue];
    sqlStatement = sqlite3_mprintf("UPDATE facts SET isFavorite = 'no' WHERE id=%d", affectedFactId);

Thanks again, cheers